# GStreamer RTPBIN Forward Error Correction from gst-launch invocation

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, gstreamer, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

I would like to add forward error correction to the gstream transmit and receive stream commands as launched through gst-launch-1.0 at the end of this question.
Specifically I am using rtpbin which exposes two request pads to allow for attaching forward error correction "request-fec-decoder" and "request-fec-encoder".
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtpmanager/rtpbin.html?gi-language=c
The forward error correction I would like to use is provided by "rtpulpfecenc" and "rtpulpfecdec".
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp/rtpulpfecenc.html?gi-language=c
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp/rtpulpfecdec.html?gi-language=c

Unfortunately I can't find any examples online that show how to attach request pads to rtpbin via a gst-launch call. Does anyone know if this is possible? If so any hints as to how one does this would be appreciated as I'm not really sure where to start.

The rtpbin doc page says something about needing to request an auxiliary streams, but it doesn't make much sense to me in the context of a gst-launch command.

> GstRtpBin has signals (#GstRtpBin::request-aux-sender and GstRtpBin::request-aux-receiver to dynamically request an element that can be used to create or merge additional RTP streams. AUX elements are needed to implement FEC or retransmission (such as RFC 4588). An AUX sender must have one sink_%u pad that matches the sessionid in the signal and it should have 1 or more src_%u pads. For each src_%\u pad, a session will be made (if needed) and the pad will be linked to the session send_rtp_sink pad. Each session will then expose its source pad as send_rtp_src_%u on GstRtpBin. An AUX receiver has 1 src_%u pad that much match the sessionid in the signal and 1 or more sink_%u pads. A session will be made for each sink_%u pad when the corresponding recv_rtp_sink_%u pad is requested on GstRtpBin. The GstRtpBin::request-jitterbuffer signal can be used to provide a custom element to perform arrival time smoothing, reordering and optionally packet loss detection and retransmission requests.

The command I am attempting to add it to is below (just to give some reference).

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtpbin name=rtpbin_o \
         rpicamsrc rotation=90 bitrate=800000 preview=1 preview-encoded=1 fullscreen=0 preview-x=20 preview-y=20 preview-w=320 preview-h=190 do-timestamp=1 ! video/x-h264,width=800,height=448,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! rtph264pay ! rtpbin_o.send_rtp_sink_0 \
                   rtpbin_o.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000                            \
                   rtpbin_o.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5001 sync=false async=false    \
         udpsrc port=5005 ! rtpbin_o.recv_rtcp_sink_0                           \
         alsasrc device=hw:2,0 do-timestamp=1 ! queue ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,rate=48000,channels=2 ! opusenc bitrate=96000 ! rtpopuspay ! rtpbin_o.send_rtp_sink_1                   \
                   rtpbin_o.send_rtp_src_1 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5002                            \
                   rtpbin_o.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5003 sync=false async=false    \
         udpsrc port=5007 ! rtpbin_o.recv_rtcp_sink_1
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtpbin name=rtpbin_i                                          \
     udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264" port=5000 ! rtpbin_i.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin_i. ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! v4l2h264dec capture-io-mode=4 ! xvimagesink \
     udpsrc port=5001 ! rtpbin_i.recv_rtcp_sink_0 rtpbin_i.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5005 sync=false async=false        \
     udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio,clock-rate=(int)48000,encoding-name=(string)OPUS" port=5002 ! rtpbin_i.recv_rtp_sink_1 rtpbin_i. ! rtpopusdepay ! opusdec ! alsasink device=hw:1,0 \
     udpsrc port=5003 ! rtpbin_i.recv_rtcp_sink_1 rtpbin_i.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5007 sync=false async=false
```